# Error multiple primary keys constraint in Keycloak using YugabyteDB

Tags: azure, kubernetes, keycloak, kubernetes-helm

We have got the following stack and deploy `Keycloak` helm-chart (using Yugabyte DB) through Terraform

```
Cloud       - Azure
K8S Version - 1.27.3
Keycloak    - Helm Chart
```

and it failed with the following error

Error Message:

```
base info: {databaseUrl=jdbc:postgresql://yugabyte.svc.cluster.local:5432/postgres, databaseUser=keycloak, databaseProduct=PostgreSQL 11.2-YB-2.19.0.0-b0, databaseDriver=PostgreSQL JDBC Driver 42.2.5}
INFO  [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) Updating database. Using changelog META-INF/jpa-changelog-master.xml
ERROR [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) Error has occurred while updating the database: liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set META-INF/jpa-changelog-3.4.0.xml::3.4.0::keycloak:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: multiple primary keys for table "realm_default_roles" are not allowed [Failed SQL: (0) ALTER TABLE public.REALM_DEFAULT_ROLES ADD CONSTRAINT CONSTRAINT_REALM_DEFAULT_ROLES PRIMARY KEY (REALM_ID, ROLE_ID)]
```

I am running out of ideas as how this should be resolved and `keycloak` works fine on `K8S` version `1.23` and `1.24`

Comment: I can only guess, but perhaps there could be some type of race condition between the different replicas in your K8s cluster. I mean, different nodes trying executing the same Liquibase migration. It is difficult to say because Liquibase usually deal with this staff gratefully, but it may explain your problem. For testing purposes, try deploying Keycloak in a single K8s replica and see if it works.

Comment: did you find a solution on this?

Comment: @nicoschuck Sorry, nope.  We stopped using Yugabyte and moved on to use Postgres